# My CollectionView with custom cells keeps crashing the program, even tho it initially compiles/runs

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a UICollectionView in which cells have textLabels in them, and the program compiles, runs, but crashes when I try to segue to the screen with this table.

It has a custom cell class, called GridViewCell with one field, and the custom class inherits from UICollectionViewCell. The code for the ViewController is:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GridViewController : UICollectionViewController{

    @IBOutlet var gridView: UICollectionView! //this is the ViewController

    var someArray1 : [String] = []
    var someArray2 : [String] = []
    var totalSize: Int {
    return entireArray.count
    }
    var entireArray: [[String]] {
        return combine(someArray1, someArray2) //combine takes the arrays and makes a 2D array with both of them in it
    }
    let subArraySize = 4


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  totalSize * subArraySize
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> GridViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GridViewCell{
            cell.textLabel.text = "ddd" //sample text just to test it
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            return cell
        }
        else {
            DLog("error")
            return GridViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I get in the debugger is:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling - dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'"

In my interface builder, I HAVE specified the reuse identifier to be "gridCell" and its class is GridViewCell.

how can I rectify this?

Comment: Check that the reuse identifier for the cell corresponds to: gridCell

Comment: I've done that, and in the Interface Builder, I made sure to do that

Comment: You registered UICollectionViewCell and you are trying to cast it as GridViewCell

Comment: I think that you don't have to register new cell if you are using Interface builder

Comment: when I change the line with "register" to GridView and GridViewCell, I get: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" And I also get that if I comment out the register line

Comment: in your viewDidLoad change it to following
self.gridView.register(UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")

Comment: Are you using a XIB? -ok, a lot of comments in a moment. Anyway, if you're using a xib for the cell, you have to register the nib, like the comment on top of mine.  self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gridCell") -

Comment: @saroshmirza I get Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UINib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)'

Comment: @Derry did you tried with

self.gridView.register(UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")

or

self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")

Comment: @saroshmirza for the first one, I get Argument labels '(_:, forCellReuseIdentifier:)' do not match any available overloads, the second gives Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UINib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)'

Comment: Can you please show the code what you tried

Comment: @Derry please change collectionView cellForItemAt to following to see what error it gives

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GridViewCell{
            cell.textLabel.text = "ddd" //sample text just to test it
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            return cell
    }

Comment: Do you really need gridView outlet if you are already inhriting from UICollectionViewController, are you using collectionview inside collectionview, maybe thats where the problem is

Comment: Make this change as per my understanding. UICollectionViewCell does not have identifier you have mentioned rather GridViewCell. Hope will fix the issue.
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(GridViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")
    }

Comment: May be if you can show the storyboard screenshot we can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (if you are not using Interface Builder)

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(GridViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")
}
```

If you are loading a cell from storyboard, then you dont need to register the cell

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
            super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

If you are loading a cell from nib/xib then you can do something like this:

```
self.collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "GridViewCell")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cellForItemAt to the following

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GridViewCell{
        cell.textLabel.text = "ddd" //sample text just to test it
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some minor changes in your code according to Xcode 7.3, hope will help you.

```
class GridViewController: UICollectionViewController {

@IBOutlet var gridView: UICollectionView!

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("gridCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    return cell }
}
```

This works fine as I have tested it.

Comment: I now get a new error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

Comment: Provide any number in numberOfItemsInSection function then try once more. You got an error of invalid index path.

Comment: as you can see, that function does return a value. Can you elaborate precisely where/what I need to edit?

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was calling "collectionView.register(, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: <#T##String#>)" instead of      collectionView.register(, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: <#T##String#>)